# php: receive json from POST and save to file

Tags: php, json

I want to receive a POST request from a JS client with a json body (i.e. this is **not** form data), and save the .gigs (javascript) array to a file, after checking the .password field.  This is all my code (based on [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php?rq=1))

```
$json_params = file_get_contents("php://input");

if (strlen($json_params) > 0 && isValidJSON($json_params)){
    /* json_decode(..., true) returns an 'array', not an 'object'
   * Working combination: json_decode($json_params) WITH $inp->password
   */
  $inp = json_decode($json_params);
} else {
    echo "could not decode POST body";
    return;
}

$password = $inp->password;
// echo $password;

if ($password == "****") {
  $gigs = $inp['gigs'];
  // WAS $res = file_put_contents('gigs.json', json_encode($gigs), TEXT_FILE);
  $res = file_put_contents('gigs.json', json_encode($gigs));

  if ($res > 0) {
    echo "Success";
    return;
  } else {
    if (!$res) {
      http_response_code(500);
      echo "file_put_contents error:".$res;
      return;
    } else {
      http_response_code(500);
      echo "Error: saved zero data!";
      return;
    }
  }
} 
else {
  // http_response_code(403);      // (2)
  echo "Password invalid";
  return;
}
```

What I find is that

- if I comment out the `if` statement and uncomment `echo $password;` then the right password is there
- if I uncomment line 2, which I want to do, then I get back a 500 and the error logs refer an `Illegal string offset 'password'` in line (1) above. Without that I get back a `"Success"` (all for the same password).

I don't understand what is happening, nor how to get 200, 403 and  500 error messages safely.

Comment: why you say `POST request` while you are reading `php://input`? Also `$inp = "I never got set";` -> that's what `null` is usually for.

Comment: That may be an abuse of words by my. I am sending an ajax POST from the client. I don't understand PHP at all, so I may well be doing something very wrong.

Comment: Well, you are doing most things wrong there

Comment: If you use `true` in `json_decode()` it returns an array, not an object.

Comment: I've tried with and without `true`. When I toggle, I see that I need different ways to access the json content, but in either case I still get problems if I uncomment line (2)

Answer (score 1):

Note

```
$json_params = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

If your scripts are running upon regular HTTP requests, passing data like it comes from HTML form, them you should consider using `$_POST` for your content, not `php://input`. If you expect JSON in request body, then I'd be fine, yet I'd also check content type for `application/json`.

Next:

```
$inp = "I never got set";

if (strlen($json_params) > 0 && isValidJSON($json_params)){
  $inp = json_decode($json_params, true);
}

$password = $inp->password;
$password = $inp['password'];
```

This is pretty broken. First, see `json_decode()` arguments (2nd) -> you are decoding to array (`true`), not object (`false`), so only `$password = $inp['password'];` will work in your case. Also the whole code will fail when your input data is invalid as in that case `$np` is rubbish string, not the array you try to read later on. Use `null` as default value and check for that prior further use.

Next:

```
$res = file_put_contents('gigs.json', json_encode($gigs), FILE_TEXT);
```

there's no `FILE_TEXT` option for `file_put_contents()`. Nor you'd need one.

Once you correct these you'd be fine. Also `print_r()` and `var_dump()` may be the functions you wish to get familiar with for your further debugging.

In general http://php.net/ -> lookup for functions you are about to use.

Comment: Thanks - your advice regarding `php://input` contradicts the majority of comments on SO I found, but I will try it if I can work out how to use it (php.net seems to be unreachable at present)

Comment: Do you suggest using - or not using - `true` in the json_decode? I know that my one of my two `$password =` must be wrong but which is the better way to do it?

Comment: `$_POST` can only be used with standard form encodings (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`). I believe the OP is expecting JSON as request body, so `php://input` should be fine.

Comment: If your whole code is OOP, then I'd personally prefer having JSON object too, but in your particular case it does not matter really. Choose what you like better.